# Riemann sum limit of function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits

I was wondering which of the two following statements was correct and why:

$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(\frac{i}{N},g(\frac{i}{N}))=\int_0^1 f(u,g(u))du$

$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(\frac{i}{N},\frac{g(i)}{N}))=\int_0^1 f(u,g(u))du$

I am not sure how the rescaling works when the second variable is a function of the first variable as in the two statements above. If you could refer me to some online material or suggest some alternative literature it would be great. Many thanks!